# What is the link between elevated estrogen and lowered alkaline phosphatase?

Tags: endocrinology, enzyme, hormonal-imbalance

[This Wikipdia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_phosphatase#Lowered_levels) lists several conditions or diseases that may lead to reduced levels of alkaline phosphatase (AP).

Among them are:

- postmenopausal women receiving estrogen therapy because of aging
- taking oral contraceptives (the linked study investigated combined OCP)

I assume, in both cases the hormones themselves (estrogen, maybe also progestogen) somehow influence the AP-levels. 
If it is correct:

**Is the reaction cascade known, that leads from the hormone(s) to the reduced AP levels?**

So far, I could only find studies that confirmed there *is* a link between estrogen and AP levels, for example [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1016/S0736-0266%2801%2900092-4) or [this](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/youton1964/22/3/22_3_163/_article/-char/en). However, I am interested in the details here.